# How to get this coming Sunday's date?

Tags: mysql

I need to get "this coming Sunday"'s date

How could I do this?

I've seen the `DAYOFWEEK` function but that's not really what I'm after (might be useful in the WHERE clause)

EDIT:

I changed question back from my change to Saturday to the original Sunday since I got some valid answers for Sunday and it may help some people in the future

I found a number of other 'end of week' date questions and answers elsewhere (including here on SO)

The most useful solution for me was the accepted answer found [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/283001-find-end-of-week-date-saturday/).

Comment: Show us your code so far.

Comment: Just being pedantic, but Sunday is the FIRST day of the week, not the last.

Comment: @beercodebeer treating Sunday as the last day of the week is explicitly supported by MySQL: see the `mode' argument of the WEEK function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: Thanks @beercodebeer you're right, I'm after Saturday :)

Comment: @Adam, my code was getting pretty "out there" looking so I omitted it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Better use `curdate()` instead of `now()`, so the final conversion to `DATE` type via `date()` can be omitted.

```
SELECT curdate() + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(curdate()) DAY;
```

for next sunday or

```
SET @date = '2014-03-05';

SELECT @date + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(@date) DAY;
```

for a variable date.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Simply use this statement for the next sunday:

```
SELECT date(now() + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(now()) DAY);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| date(now() + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(now()) DAY) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2014-04-13                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**Explanation:**

`weekday(now())` returns the current weekday (starting with 0 for monday, 6 is sunday). Subtract the current weekday from 6 and get the remaining days until next sunday as a result. Then add them to the current date and get next sunday's date.

Or if you want to keep it flexible to work with any date:

```
SET @date = '2014-03-05';

SELECT date(@date + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(@date) DAY);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| date(@date + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(@date) DAY) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2014-03-09                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @Drewdavid weekday(now()) returns the current weekday (starting with 0 for monday). 6 is sunday. So, I do 6 - 4 and have the days remaining till next sunday.

Comment: Yes I think I figured it out by breaking it down and running the query in its smaller parts to see what the output was. Thanks this is just what I was trying to do (without knowing the weekday function) :)

Comment: @KenWhite - You're totally right. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Drewdavid - I improved the code, again. See my update.

Comment: Hi, please see my revision to Saturday instead of Sunday, what is needed to adapt to this?

Comment: @Drewdavid - See the explanation in my answer: 0 is Monday and 6 is Sunday, so you simply have to change 6 to 5 for a Saturday. But please don't change your question and title. Now all answers are wrong, because they refer to Sunday.

Comment: Hi, understood. I'll change my question back to Sunday since it may help someone in the future, I found some other answers for getting the 'end of week' date (i.e. Saturday) which I will share in my question. :)

Comment: @Drewdavid - Thanks! BTW, your linked answer is the same as mine, only using `dayofweek()` instead of `weekday()`. The only difference is [**dayofweek()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) has saturday at index 7 and [**weekday()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) has saturday at index 5. So, I don't understand why this should be considered a better answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being thick, but if the `WEEKDAY()` of today is greater than the day of week desired, it gets the _previous_ date for that day of the week, not the _next_ date, no?  I know the solution technically answers the original question as it works for Sunday, but it cannot, as you said above, be applied to Saturday or any other day of the week.  e.g. `SELECT '2019-01-27' + INTERVAL 5 - WEEKDAY('2019-01-27') DAY;` yields `2019-01-26`.  (The 27th is a Sunday and the 26th is a Saturday for reference.)

Comment: As a follow-up to myself, [I posted a generalized version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870329/what-is-the-mysql-alternative-to-oracles-next-day-function/54375541#54375541) (which granted is less succinct).  Hopefully that helps anyone out who might've googled the problem and found themselves here, as I did.

Answer (score 1):

To find the next date for given week day use this query. set the value of the week day you want in the ***THEDAY*** variable.

```
    SET @THEDAY = 1;
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL if( @THEDAY > WEEKDAY(NOW()) , (@THEDAY - WEEKDAY(NOW())) ,  (7 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) + @THEDAY) DAY)
```

**Note that the weekday index starts from 0 For Monday ...... 6 For Sunday**

Answer (score 0):

```
Date()+8-WeekDay(Date())
```

and try this

```
=IIf(Weekday(Now())=1,DateAdd("d",7,Now()),
IIf(Weekday(Now())=2,DateAdd("d",6,Now()),
IIf(Weekday(Now())=3,DateAdd("d",5,Now()),
IIf(Weekday(Now())=4,DateAdd("d",4,Now()),
IIf(Weekday(Now())=5,DateAdd("d",3,Now()),
IIf(Weekday(Now())=6,DateAdd("d",2,Now()), 
IIf(Weekday(Now())=6,DateAdd("d",1,Now()) )))))))
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid MySQL SQL syntax. Can you explain how it works in MySQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the [WEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function can be paired with [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for a nice one-liner:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),WEEK(NOW(),1), ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') as `this Sunday`;
+-------------+
| this Sunday |
+-------------+
| 2014-04-13  |
+-------------+;
```

If you follow the doc links, the overall strategy is mostly gleaned from the note on STR_TO_DATE about year/week conversion. Then the mode argument to WEEK is used to treat Sunday as the last instead of first day of the week. Essentially, we construct a string like this:

```
'201415 Sunday'
```

Which is to be interpreted as "in 2014, Sunday of the 15th week".

Just in case, I tested this at the year boundary... looks okay so far!

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR('2014-12-31'),WEEK('2014-12-31',1), ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') as `this Sunday`;
+-------------+
| this Sunday |
+-------------+
| 2015-01-04  |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar answer in [What is the MySQL alternative to Oracle's NEXT_DAY function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870329/what-is-the-mysql-alternative-to-oracles-next-day-function/51879395#51879395) which a more general solution to the question being asked here. The solution below will help you get to any specified next day (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday or Saturday) similar to the `NEXT_DAY()` function in oracle.

**Short Version:**

Utilizing `DAYOFWEEK()` you can leverage the number values to create a closed formula that tells you how many days to add. You can then utilize DATE_ADD to help you shift the date. There may be a cleaner way, however you should be able to make a function out of this.

The following is an Excel formula, which you use to verify all 49 use cases: `=MOD(MOD(Next-Input, 7)+7,7)`

Some examples of how the excel calculations can be translated into SQL:

```
SELECT (((1-DAYOFWEEK('2018-08-15')) % 7)+7) % 7 AS DaysToAddToGetNextSundayFromWednesday 
FROM dual; -- 4

SELECT DATE_ADD('2018-08-15', INTERVAL (((1-DAYOFWEEK('2018-08-15')) % 7)+7) % 7 DAY) AS NextSundayFromDate 
FROM dual; -- 2018-08-19
```

If you plan to use the above often, you'll probably want to make a function or stored procedure.

**Long Version:**

I've run into this problem multiple times over the years. First time I created a giant case statement for all 49 cases. I found that this made the queries super big and not clean. I wanted a cleaner, simpler solution like a closed in formula. Below are details to to calculations I did to confirm the formula above works. I tested this with `MySQL 5.7` if you are using MySQL 8.5 it looks like the function is built in ( Reference: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/next_day ).

*Note: Excel doesn't return negative results for modulus, where MySQL does. That is why we add 7 and do another modulus.*

```
DAYOFWEEK()         
Sun     1       
Mon     2       
Tues    3       
Wed     4       
Thur    5       
Fri     6       
Sat     7       

Input   Next    Expected Days to Add    Formula Result
1       1       0                       0
1       2       1                       1
1       3       2                       2
1       4       3                       3
1       5       4                       4
1       6       5                       5
1       7       6                       6
2       1       6                       6
2       2       0                       0
2       3       1                       1
2       4       2                       2
2       5       3                       3
2       6       4                       4
2       7       5                       5
3       1       5                       5
3       2       6                       6
3       3       0                       0
3       4       1                       1
3       5       2                       2
3       6       3                       3
3       7       4                       4
4       1       4                       4
4       2       5                       5
4       3       6                       6
4       4       0                       0
4       5       1                       1
4       6       2                       2
4       7       3                       3
5       1       3                       3
5       2       4                       4
5       3       5                       5
5       4       6                       6
5       5       0                       0
5       6       1                       1
5       7       2                       2
6       1       2                       2
6       2       3                       3
6       3       4                       4
6       4       5                       5
6       5       6                       6
6       6       0                       0
6       7       1                       1
7       1       1                       1
7       2       2                       2
7       3       3                       3
7       4       4                       4
7       5       5                       5
7       6       6                       6
7       7       0                       0
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will return previous Saturday on Sunday.
If you need the next Saturday for Sunday use this

```
SELECT 
CAST(
  Case When weekday(now()) = 6 Then (now() + INTERVAL weekday(now()) DAY)
    else (now() +  INTERVAL 5 - weekday(now()) DAY)
  end 
As Date) as saturday
```