# What is the MySQL alternative to Oracle's NEXT_DAY function?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

`NEXT_DAY("01-SEP-95","FRIDAY")` returns what is the date on next Friday, but in MySQL this function does not seem to be appear. What is the alternative?

Comment: I can see some implementations of this online, but I agree that they all seem a bit cumbersome. I suspect someone here can do better - athough the custom function idea is fine too.

Comment: You'll probably want to specify that this is for MySQL 5.7 or versions before 8.5?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw my hat in the ring with yet another approach:

***Edit:***  I realize somewhat belatedly that the Oracle function in question takes a string as the second argument, and so this doesn't precisely fit the requirement.  However MySQL has already kindly defined 0 - 6 as Monday - Sunday, and anyway I have moral objections to using a string as an argument for this type of thing.  A string would either come from user input **or** yet another mapping in higher level code between numeric and string values.  Why not pass an integer?  :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fnDayOfWeekGetNext`(
        p_date DATE,
        p_weekday TINYINT(3)
        ) RETURNS date
BEGIN

        RETURN DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL p_weekday - WEEKDAY(p_date) + (ROUND(WEEKDAY(p_date) / (p_weekday + WEEKDAY(p_date) + 1)) * 7) DAY);

END
```

To break the portion down that determines the `INTERVAL` value:

The first part of the equation simply gets the offset between the weekday specified and the weekday of the date specified:

```
p_weekday - WEEKDAY(p_date)
```

This will return a positive number if `p_weekday` is greater than `WEEKDAY(p_date)` and vice versa.  Zero will be returned if they're the same.

The `ROUND()` segment is used to determine whether the requested day of the week (`p_weekday`) has already occurred in the current week relative to the date (`p_date`) specified.  So, by example...

```
ROUND(WEEKDAY('2019-01-25') / (6 + WEEKDAY('2019-01-25') + 1))
```

..returns `0`, indicating that Sunday (`6`) has not occurred this week, as `2019-01-25` is a Friday.  Likewise...

```
ROUND(WEEKDAY('2019-01-25') / (2 + WEEKDAY('2019-01-25') + 1))
```

...returns `1` because Wednesday (`2`) has already passed.  Note that this will return `0` if `p_weekday` is the same as the weekday of `p_date`.

This value (either `1` or `0`) is then multiplied by the constant `7` (the number of days in a week).

Hence if `p_weekday` has already occurred in the current week, it will add 7 to the offset `p_weekday - WEEKDAY(p_date)`, because that offset would be a negative number and we want a date in the future.

If `p_weekday` has yet to occur in the current week, then we can just add the offset to the current date because the offset will be a positive number.  Hence the section `ROUND(...) * 7` is equal to zero and, in essence, ignored.

**My desire for this approach was to simulate an `IF()` condition mathematically.  This would be equally valid:**

```
RETURN DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL p_weekday - WEEKDAY(p_date) + IF(p_weekday - WEEKDAY(p_date) < 0, 7, 0) DAY);
```

And in the interest of objectivity, in running 1M iterations a few times of each function the `IF`-based version averaged about 4.2% faster than the `ROUND`-based version.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can create user defined function

```
DELIMITER //
 
  CREATE FUNCTION next_day(start_date DATETIME, weekday CHAR(20))
    RETURNS DATETIME
  BEGIN
    DECLARE start DATETIME;
    DECLARE i INT;
 
    // Select the next date
    SET start = ADDDATE(start_date, 1);
    SET i = 1;
 
    days: LOOP
          -- Compare the day names
        IF SUBSTR(DAYNAME(start), 1, 3) = SUBSTR(weekday, 1, 3) THEN    
       LEAVE days;
        END IF;
 
        // Select the next date
        SET start = ADDDATE(start, 1);
        SET i = i + 1;
 
        -- Not valid weekday specified
        IF i > 7 THEN
       SET start = NULL;
       LEAVE days;
    END IF;
 
     END LOOP days;
 
     RETURN start;
  END;
  //
 
   DELIMITER ;
```

and call it

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY("1995-09-01","FRIDAY")
```

Source : http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/next_day

Comment: That means no inbuilt function is there to get the result?

Comment: @Madhivanan - I'm not a MySQL person but why not just do ADDDATE(start, 7) and if the dayname is the same then we are good. the loop seems a bit over the top. Admittedly I may be missing a MySQL trick as that isn't something I've used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to a different problem:

Find the date for Friday of the current week:-

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2017',(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%U')),' Friday'),'%Y %U %W') x;
+------------+
| x          |
+------------+
| 2017-05-12 |
+------------+
```

The above hasn't been verified for robustness, but is provided 'as is' merely as food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53ce32/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value DATE );

INSERT INTO your_table ( value )
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-14' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value,
       ADDDATE(
        value,
         6 - DAYOFWEEK( value )
           + CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK( value ) < 6 THEN 0 ELSE 7 END
       ) AS next_friday
FROM   your_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53ce32/2/0)**:

```
|                 value |           next_friday |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| May, 08 2017 00:00:00 | May, 12 2017 00:00:00 |
| May, 09 2017 00:00:00 | May, 12 2017 00:00:00 |
| May, 10 2017 00:00:00 | May, 12 2017 00:00:00 |
| May, 11 2017 00:00:00 | May, 12 2017 00:00:00 |
| May, 12 2017 00:00:00 | May, 19 2017 00:00:00 |
| May, 13 2017 00:00:00 | May, 19 2017 00:00:00 |
| May, 14 2017 00:00:00 | May, 19 2017 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Version:**

Utilizing `DAYOFWEEK()` you can leverage the number values to create a closed formula that tells you how many days to add. You can then utilize DATE_ADD to help you shift the date. There may be a cleaner way, however you should be able to make a function out of this.

The following is an Excel formula, which you use to verify all 49 use cases: `=MOD(MOD(Next-Input, 7)+7,7)`

Some examples of how the excel calculations can be translated into SQL:

```
SELECT (((1-DAYOFWEEK('2018-08-15')) % 7)+7) % 7 AS DaysToAddToGetNextSundayFromWednesday 
FROM dual; -- 4

SELECT DATE_ADD('2018-08-15', INTERVAL (((1-DAYOFWEEK('2018-08-15')) % 7)+7) % 7 DAY) AS NextSundayFromDate 
FROM dual; -- 2018-08-19
```

If you plan to use the above often, you'll probably want to make a function or stored procedure.

**Long Version:**

I've run into this problem multiple times over the years. First time I created a giant case statement for all 49 cases. I found that this made the queries super big and not clean. I wanted a cleaner, simpler solution like a closed in formula. Below are details to to calculations I did to confirm the formula above works. I tested this with `MySQL 5.7` if you are using MySQL 8.5 it looks like the function is built in ( Reference: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/next_day ).

*Note: Excel doesn't return negative results for modulus, where MySQL does. That is why we add 7 and do another modulus.*

```
DAYOFWEEK()         
Sun     1       
Mon     2       
Tues    3       
Wed     4       
Thur    5       
Fri     6       
Sat     7       

Input   Next    Expected Days to Add    Formula Result
1       1       0                       0
1       2       1                       1
1       3       2                       2
1       4       3                       3
1       5       4                       4
1       6       5                       5
1       7       6                       6
2       1       6                       6
2       2       0                       0
2       3       1                       1
2       4       2                       2
2       5       3                       3
2       6       4                       4
2       7       5                       5
3       1       5                       5
3       2       6                       6
3       3       0                       0
3       4       1                       1
3       5       2                       2
3       6       3                       3
3       7       4                       4
4       1       4                       4
4       2       5                       5
4       3       6                       6
4       4       0                       0
4       5       1                       1
4       6       2                       2
4       7       3                       3
5       1       3                       3
5       2       4                       4
5       3       5                       5
5       4       6                       6
5       5       0                       0
5       6       1                       1
5       7       2                       2
6       1       2                       2
6       2       3                       3
6       3       4                       4
6       4       5                       5
6       5       6                       6
6       6       0                       0
6       7       1                       1
7       1       1                       1
7       2       2                       2
7       3       3                       3
7       4       4                       4
7       5       5                       5
7       6       6                       6
7       7       0                       0
```