Last Sunday until this upcoming Sunday with time
I am trying to retrieve the last recent Sunday at 3 AM until this upcoming Sunday 2:59 AM.
Below is what I have but it doesn't retrieve exactly the upcoming Sunday. Ideally, whenever I run this query, it should provide me with the expected result. For example, if I run this query today, it should return StartDate: 8/25/2024 3:00 AM and EndDate: 9/1/2024 2:59 AM while if I run next week, it should provide me with StartDate: 9/1/2024 3:00 AM and EndDate: 9/8/2024 2:59 AM
One main concern is, if I were to run this query on a Sunday. Some places have the week start on Sunday while others on Monday so the query should take that into account and have the result of being Sunday - Sunday.
select dateadd(hour,3,dateadd(minute, 00, DATEADD(dd,  DATEDIFF(dd,-1,GETDATE())/7*7,-1))) StartDate,
dateadd(hour,+2,dateadd(minute, +59, dateadd(day, ((15-@@datefirst) - datepart(dw, getdate())) % 7, convert(char(12), getdate()))))  EndDate


This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020162/how-to-get-this-coming-sundays-date

@testing-for-ya, I know it's a very weird request but that is something that was asked and wasn't my decision.

Should the answer be different if asked before 03:00 vs after 03:00 on a Sunday?  For SQL Server 2022 or later, the DATE_BUCKET() function may come in handy - example DATE_BUCKET (week, 1, GETDATE(), CAST('20240107 03:00' AS DATETIME)). For earlier SQL server versions, a combination of DATEDIFF(), truncation, and DATEADD() can be used, but we must choose a reference Sunday before any expected date value - DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(hour, '19000107 03:00', GETDATE())/168, '19000107 03:00') Fiddle. (Minutes/1440 or seconds/86400 could also be used.)

@TN it would be from 3AM
